# How load html template in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, templates

I use vue.js and vue-router.js.
I added both of files to a html page

This is my component for load template...
`const Dashboard = {template: "<strong>"}`

But I want load html page dynamically and with ***HTTP URL***. 
`const Dashboard = {template: "How load html page with url(http)"}`

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating layers, you can create vue component and use `slot`

Layout.vue

```
<template>
  Header
  AnyComponents
  <slot />
  Footer
</template>
```

and in your page component you should import your layout and wrap

MainPage.vue

```
<template>
  <MainLayout>
    Here is your conntent of page or router
    <router-view />
  </MainLayout>
</template>

<script>
import MainLayout from 'layout.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    MainLayout
  }
}
</script>
```

And now for render your page you should use your page in router

example of router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router'

import MainPage from 'MainPage.vue';

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: MainPage,
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you could define a component similar to this

```
Vue.component('dynamic-component', {
    props: {
        contentURL: String,
    },
    template: `<div v-html='inner_html'></div>`,
    computed: {
        inner_html() {
            return // http call to get html value utilizing this.contentURL
        },
    },
});
```

then from the router

```
{
    path: '/path/option-a',
    components: {
        DynamicComponent
    },
    props: {
        contentURL: `https://some-resource/option-a`
    }
},
{
    path: '/path/option-b',
    components: {
        DynamicComponent
    },
    props: {
        contentURL: `https://some-resource/option-b`
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems the right way. I had expected to find it in some of the webpages for Vue resources, examples, components, etc... Pity there is not a Vue "stdlib"

Comment: btw... axios.get() is always a Promise, isn't it?

Comment: @arivero yeah, I was just stubbing in the http call, I don't know that OP uses axios so I use removed that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert html to your page, use `v-html`

```
<div class="content" v-html="dashboard.template">
</div>
```

Comment: No ... I want make a layout and load html templates in <router-view></router-view> by url